# Failed to convert property value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [java.lang.Integer]

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am using Spring MVC and Spring Security and hibernate. iam having problem with save 'Phone Number" to "database". where is mistake?

I get the Following Error When i submit my form

```
Failed to convert property value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [java.lang.Integer] for property Phone_Number; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "(020)828-5852"
```

this is my view:

```
    <div class="control-group ">
 <label class="control-label" for="phone" >Phone Number</label>
  <div class="controls">
  <form:input id="phone" path="Phone_Number" type="text"
   class="form-control span4"/>
   <div class="has-error">
   <form:errors path="Phone_Number" class="help-inline" />
   </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

The model:

```
@NotNull
    @Column(name="PHONE_NUMBER", nullable=false)
    private Integer Phone_Number;
```

My Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = { "/newuser" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String newUser(ModelMap model) {
        UsersInfo usersInfo = new UsersInfo();
        model.addAttribute("usersInfo", usersInfo);
        model.addAttribute("edit", false);
        model.addAttribute("loggedinuser", getPrincipal());
        return "adduser";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = { "/newuser" }, method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String saveUser(@Valid UsersInfo usersInfo, BindingResult result, ModelMap model) {


        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            return "adduser";
        }


        if (!userInfoService.isUserUserNameUnique(usersInfo.getIdUsers(), usersInfo.getUserName())) {
            FieldError UsernameError = new FieldError("usersInfo", "UserName", messageSource
                    .getMessage("non.unique.UserName", new String[] { usersInfo.getUserName() }, Locale.getDefault()));
            result.addError(UsernameError);
            return "adduser";
        }
```

I read i am to add this Bean to my hibernate configuration

```
@Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
        return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    }
```

But the Error Message is still there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The number you try to send in the form is not valid Integer - it consists brackets. You should change Phone_Number type on you model to String in this case.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to handle the phone number as a int, make sure the param received from the view is a Integer.

You could try line this:

```
<form:input id="phone" path="Phone_Number" type="number" class="form-control span4"/>
```